# How to add File class in flutter that accept image from device?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am working with blog app using flutter and I have to upload image from device but the problem is I am not able to create 'File image;' class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class AddBlog extends StatefulWidget {
const AddBlog({super.key});

@override
State<AddBlog> createState() => _AddBlogState();
}

class _AddBlogState extends State<AddBlog> {
@override
File _image; ***//this line shows error***
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text("Post Blog"),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    reverse: true,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green.shade200,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
              child: ClipRect()),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.0,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Form(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Title",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Description",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .06,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text(
                        "Post",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

flutter doctor -v result:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22623.1095], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.7.1 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 7048ed95a5 (5 days ago), 2023-02-01 09:07:31 -0800
• Engine revision 800594f1f4
• Dart version 2.19.1
• DevTools version 2.20.1

This is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\sures\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-33-ext4, build-tools 33.0.1
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.4)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.4.33213.308
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[√] VS Code (version 1.75.0)
• VS Code at C:\Users\sures\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
• M2003J15SC (mobile) • 07034cfa0406 • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
• Windows (desktop)   • windows      • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22623.1095]
• Chrome (web)        • chrome       • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.120
• Edge (web)          • edge         • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 109.0.1518.78

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

Comment: Need more clarity to the question.

Comment: add the error msg in the question that would help others answer more aptly

Answer (score 0):

`File` class is part of `dart:io` library so add this and try once more
`import 'dart:io';`